# Неофиты вставляют пустые строки в код

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, форматирование

Замечал, что многие новые пользователи часто вставляют в свои сообщения код, в котором каждая вторая строка пустая, причём встречал это как тут, так и на enSO . Думал это связано с каким-то распространённым кривым редактором, но как OP описал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272595/c-%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be#12726060), он сделал это из-за того, что об этом попросило некое сообщение об ошибке. Я предполагаю, что это какая-то статическая проверка сообщений новых пользователей.

Собственно что это за проверка? Какое у неё сообщение?

---

То что новички так делают плохо для всех: это лишняя работа, это затрудняет читаемость, и это невозможно поправить.

Можно ли как-то изменить саму проверку? Или перефразировать её текст? Может её стоит просто отключить?

Comment: Предположу, что это не проверка, а непонимание редактора: если вставить код просто так, он весь слепится в одну строчку (Markdown заменяет одиночные переносы строк на пробел), и вот чтобы его разлепить, некоторые додумываются ставить пустые строки (что угодно, лишь бы не использовать кнопку форматирования кода...)

Comment: @andreymal, OP там пишет, что «вылезло сообщение»

Comment: Ну, мне вылезло [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKCjj.png). Добавление пустых строк действительно фиксит это сообщение (что угодно, лишь бы не следовать рекомендации из этого сообщения...)

Comment: @andreymal, как-то сложно представить, что после такого кто-то решит наставить 2 десятка переносов строк... подозреваю, что есть ещё какое-то другое сообщение... можно с этим как-то поиграться не регя новый аккаунт?

Comment: Можно писать вопрос без регистрации, я через режим инкогнито игрался

Comment: гмм... что-то у меня ничего другого получить не удаётся... в общем хз... непонятно как-то...

Comment: Ох, ну всем же давно известно: люди читают ж***й!

Comment: @КириллМалышев, это понятно, но в таком случае как-то странно ставить 2 десятка переносов расставлять вместо того чтобы просто ещё раз нажать «отправить»... ЗЫ: а ещё я тоже ем пельмени...

Answer (score 1):

Если при публикации кода не оформить его соответствующим образом, т.е. вставить просто как голый текст, то вылезает сообщение:

> Кажется, ваше сообщение содержит код, не оформленный соответствующим образом. Пожалуйста, выделите весь код 4 отступами с помощью кнопки на панели инструментов или воспользуйтесь комбинацией клавиш CTRL+K. Чтобы получить дополнительную справку по редактированию, нажмите значок [?] в панели инструментов.

Оно хоть и выделено красным цветом, но написано достаточно мелким шрифтом. Если его прочитать и понять, то код можно оформить как следует. Но, видимо, его просто не читают толком. А из-за того, что
одиночные
переводы
строк
для обычного текста в сообщении на сайте фактически не работают (нужно либо 2 пробела в конце строки, либо 2 перевода строки), то первое инстинктивное желание - это настучать ещё переводов строк, пока строка действительно не окажется на новой линии.

Потом такое сообщение (с недооформленным кодом) видит кто-то более посвящённый в вопросы форматирования кода на Stack Overflow и делает как надо (например, через выделить блок текста и нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). Лишние переводы строк, конечно же, в таком случае остаются, так как убирать их отдельно уже чуть более заморочнее и не все на это готовы тратить время.

В качестве возможного решения проблемы можно предложить явно добавить в сообщение о проблеме с форматированием кода, что при редактировании **не надо вставлять лишние переводы строк**. Ну и может быть сделать само сообщение как-то более заметнее, нежели результат предпросмотра, в котором строки кода слиты в одну большую строку.

P.S. Любопытно, что такая проверка (с выводом сообщения про код) работает сейчас помимо ruSO только на esSO. На ptSO и на enSO её нет. А на jaSO в предпросмотре кода переносы строк есть и без дополнительных телодвижений (но теряются пробелы в начале строк), наверное, это как-то нюанс, вытекающий из особенностей японской письменности.